# django Rest frame work : token authentication

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I have a table ('like') to like post

```
class Likes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

i have a table course :

```
class Courses(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(null=True)
    like = GenericRelation(Likes)
```

i use restman opera extension to send POST request to my api
if i login with browser i get error

```
 "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
```

but i use restman only(i dont login with browser) every thing is OK

setting.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',  
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication', 
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ]
}
```

view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])  
@login_required   
def f_like(request):
    r = {'data': None}
    id_o = request.POST.get('id')
    type_o = request.POST.get('type')
    if(type_o in {'Courses', 'Course_Sessions', 'Course_Session_Exercise'} and id_o.isdigit()):
        model = eval(type_o)
        if(obj := model.objects.filter(id=id_o)):
            obj = obj[0]
            a = ['title', obj.title]
            if(c2 := obj.like.filter(user=request.user)):
                c = c2[0]
                c.delete()
                a.append(0)
            else:
                obj.like.create(user=request.user)
                a.append(1)
            r['data'] = a
    return Response(r)
```

Comment: Do you have some `@requires_csrf_token` in your `views.py`?

Comment: no i dont . i add my view

Comment: Did you add rest framework to your apps ?

Comment: yes i did add    'rest_framework' and
    'rest_framework.authtoken'  setting.py installed app

Answer (score 0):

In `setting.py` in MIDDLEWARE try to remove/comment this line:

```
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'
```

This will disable CSRF validation.

Comment: if i do that  ,hate security of my website?